# #1016 - Can't open file: './database_name/#sql-38f_36aa.frm' (errno: 24)

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have table in mysql with MyISAM storage engine.
   I want to create partition on a particular table, for this I am executing the query -

```
alter table Stops PARTITION BY KEY(`stop_id`) PARTITIONS 200
```

Where 'stop_id' is type of varchar. While executing the above query I am getting the error -

```
#1016 - Can't open file: './database_name/#sql-38f_36aa.frm' (errno: 24)
```

Can anybody please help me to resolve this problem?

Thank You.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [here](http://info.solomonson.com/content/how-fix-errno-24-mysql) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/not-enough-file-handles.html).

> errno: 24 means that too many files are open for the given process.
>   There is a read-only mysql variable called 'open_files_limit' that
>   will show how many open files are allowed by the mysqld:
>
> ```
> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'open%';
> ```
>
> A lot systems set this to something very low, like 1024.
>   Unfortunately, the following will NOT work:
>
> SET open_files_limit=100000
>
> MySQL will respond with:
>
> ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'open_files_limit' is a read only
>   variable
>
> However, it is possible to make a change to /etc/my.cnf. This file may
>   not exist, if not, just create it. Be sure it has the following
>   contents:
>
> [mysqld]
>
> ```
> open-files-limit = 100000
> ```
>
> Then, be sure to restart mysql:
>
> sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
>
> Now, SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'open%' should show 100000. The number you
>   use may be different.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, it helps me lot

Comment: Note, for Debian, the file is located at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and the variable `open_files_limit` is not there. Just add it below the `[mysqld]` section.

Comment: Same goes for my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. File is located in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and `open_files_limit` isn't there.

Comment: `adding open_files_limit = 100000` in `[mysqld]` section had no effect. `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'open%'` still shows `1024`

Comment: @Styopchik you actually have to use `open-files-limit=10000` for it to work in the cnf file, note hyphens not underscores