# MySQL error when creating table with phpmyadmin #1016

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem. I want to create a table to store images with some additional information, but I always get an error. Usually I try to fix something like this on my own, but I simply don't understand the error message...
I took a screenshot with all my settings. All fields hidden are unset except the auto-increment checkbox for ID.

Some translations:

```
Spalte = Column
Typ = Type
Länge/Werte = Length/Values
Keine(e) = Nothing
Wie definiert = Like defined
```

[image: Screenshot from my settings]

@Those who said, I should add the queries: here is a complete screenshot of Safari; there aren't any queries:[image]

Comment: Can you include the query?  That is not shown in the picture.

Comment: @tofutim, that is why web browsers zoom!  ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [#1016 - Can't open file: './database\_name/#sql-38f\_36aa.frm' (errno: 24)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390213/1016-cant-open-file-database-name-sql-38f-36aa-frm-errno-24)

Comment: @SableFoste If you can tell me how I get it.

Comment: I zoomed in, but everything looks like it is in a foreign language...

Comment: The error in your title is not the error in your image. Could this be a problem with 'user not reading error message'?

Comment: @tofutim The language is German.  @K.Biermann, There should be something above the image in PHPMYADMIN.  Something starting with `CREATE TABLE`...

Comment: Maybe I've the wrong version or settings or I'm simply too stupid, but there's nothing like you said...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that the photofield longblob is set to binary: 
change its setting from binary to blank

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `512` after [`ENUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) by comma-separated list of `ENUM` elements. E. g.

```
'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'
```

Related: [Creating ENUM variable type in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1462497/2157640)

But I must warn you that `ENUM` is intended for a small and very stable set of values. If a value is added, removed or renamed from time to time, it is better to `CREATE TABLE tags (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name TINYTEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id))` and store just foreign key referencing the `tags.id` column to your table. This implements relation of type 1:n. If more than one tag can be assigned, delete the `TAGS` column and create a two-column helper table that contains foreign key referencing `tags.id` and another foreign key referencing your table’s `ID` column. This implements relation of type n:m. You’ll need [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) get data from multiple tables.

Comment: I tried it exactly like this, but nothing changes except the error message is now "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BINARY NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `TEXT` LONGTEXT NULL, `TAGS` ENUM('Tag 1','Tag 2','' at line 1"

Comment: @K.Biermann [Vickel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20915213/2157640) already found the first error in your `CREATE TABLE` query. `BINARY` attribute is applicable to `*TEXT` only, not to `*BLOB`. See [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html).